# f_n(x,p) converge uniformly to nice f(x,p); do zeros of f_n(.,p) converge uniformly to zeros of f(.,p)?

Tags: real-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control

Fix compact intervals $X, P \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Let $f_n : X \times P \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of $C^2$ functions converging uniformly to a $C^2$ function $f$. The first and second derivatives of $f_n$ also converge uniformly to those of $f$.

For any $p \in P$, the function $f(\cdot,p) : X \to \mathbb{R}$ has a unique zero $x^*(p)$, and $f_1(x^*(p),p) \neq 0$. Therefore there is a sequence $x_n^* (p) \to x^*(p)$ such that $f_n(x_n^*(p),p)=0$ for large $n$.

When can we also say that $x_n^*(p) \to x(p)$ *uniformly* in $p$? Is there a standard reference for such results?

Comment: How about $f_n(x,p)=(x-p)^2+1/n$? This converges to $f(x,p)=(x-p)^2$,
but $f_n(x,p)\neq 0$ for all $x,p$ and $n$.
Therefore, your therefore does not seem right, unless I am misinterpreting something.

Comment: I think " $f_1(x,p)$ " denotes the partial derivative wrto the first variable, x. In other words, he's in the hypotheses of the implicit function thm.

Answer (score 1):

It's a quick proof by contradiction.

Assume  that $ x _ n ^ * $ does not converge uniformly to $x^*$. Then, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ and, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, a point $p_n\in P$ such that $|x_n  ^ *(p _ n)-x ^ *(p _ n)|\ge\epsilon$.

A subsequence $\big( p_{n_k}\, ,\, x_ {n_k}  ^ *(p _{n_k})\big)$ converges to some $( p, y ^ * ) \in P \times X$, a zero of $f$ different from $(p,x^*(p))$,  contradiction.

Comment: Note that this requires nothing about the derivatives, just uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ on $X \times P$, continuity of $f$ on $X \times P$, and the fact that $f(\cdot,p)$ has a unique zero in $X$ for each $p \in P$. 

Comment: (and compactness of $X$ and $P$)

Comment: Indeed. We may say it's an instance of a kind of general situation: "uniqueness plus compactness gives continuous dependence". 